# Pythonic way to iterate over list and create a tuple with each value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

So I have this list:

```
['test.csv', 'test2.csv']
```

I need it to have its final form like this:

```
[('test.csv', 'test.csv'),('test2.csv', 'test2.csv')]
```

What would be the best way, performance wise, to do this in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd zip:

```
[*zip(lst, lst)]
```

Benchmark on `list(map(str, range(1000)))`:

```
 28 us  [*zip(lst, lst)]
 44 us  [(file, file) for file in files]
 89 us  [(file,) * 2 for file in files]
259 us  list(map(lambda x: tuple([x] * 2), lst))
```

Or for repeating each value 10 instead of 2 times (just because someone proposed generalizing like that... I don't think it's something you'd realistically do... already your duplication is an odd thing to do):

```
 67 us  [*zip(*[lst] * 10)]
115 us  [(file,) * 10 for file in files]
287 us  list(map(lambda x: tuple([x] * 10), lst))
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDBasMwDL37K3QpsYop6XIZhX5JKCNdnE1gO8ZWoNvPZ5YNOU0HW0jvPT0p/vD3Gob3mPZ9SasHJm@JgXxcE0Oy0U6sVLa8RbhD13XKZS7ZQs7m8jvKrP0UdeZkIE3hy@pr3/eIqAT9uc4VJ/l4/qWoC99AefChRi0ypoohLGuqGVBo8gcA4Qxv//WP6W7yz3mC1w2KUWf1@HoIB9ukauVSHJbxeMnRETsKNmtUSlQ/RLJ5H/CmoISUxbt06g6tLCHrewq6HUdL10C9kIGw@adN93aBgxETBdbdaZhhy9DBCTQXe1c7FIPCb9AGw33/Aw)):

```
from timeit import repeat

setup = '''
lst = files = list(map(str, range(1000)))
'''
codes = '''
[*zip(lst, lst)]
[(file, file) for file in files]
[(file,) * 2 for file in files]
list(map(lambda x: tuple([x] * 2), lst))
'''.strip().splitlines()

for _ in range(3):
    for code in codes:
        t = min(repeat(code, setup, number=1000))
        print('%3d us ' % (t * 1e3), code)
    print()
```

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

Try this:

```
files = ['test.csv', 'test2.csv']
result = [(file, file) for file in files]
```

Answer (score 2):

Generic version of @grfreitas answer.

```py
num_times_to_duplicate = 2
files = ["test.csv", "test2.csv"]
result = [(file,) * num_times_to_duplicate for file in files]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`

```
lst = ['test.csv', 'test2.csv']
lst = list(map(lambda x: tuple([x] * 2), lst))
print(lst) # [('test.csv', 'test.csv'), ('test2.csv', 'test2.csv')]
```